# Trying to find the closed form for the nth term of $\frac{1}{1-x^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I know that $\frac{1}{1-x^4}$ is the generating function for the sequence (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...) 
I don't know how to find the closed form for the nth term though. Itried messing around with $(1 + (-1)^n) / 2$ but couldn't come up with anything. My book doesn't use mod anywhere in the chapter either so I'm assuming it can be solved without it.

Comment: I might be way off base here, but you know that $\frac{1}{1-x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{4n}$ so long as $x \in (0,1)$

Comment: I guess I thought there was a way to solve this without doing conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(1+(-1)^n) \cdot \left(1 + (-1)^{n (1 + (-1)^n)/4}\right)/4$$

But really, is this actually what's requested? This form isn't very useful.

---

If you don't mind complex numbers, to expand on on coffeemath's answer below, in general $\sum_{j=0}^k e^{2\pi i jn/k}$ is $k$ if $k|n$ and $0$ otherwise. In the case $k = 4$ this specializes to $1^n + i^n + (-1)^n + (-i)^n$ equals $4$ if $4|n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: do you mind explaining how you got this? also, they asked for the closed form of the nth term of the function. I understand that the coefficient is 1 every 4th term of the sequence. The problem I have is that my book has not solution and the examples don't cover it so I have no way to know if I'm getting what is desired. I also can't find similar problems anywhere.

Comment: The big exponent $n(1+(-1)^n)/4$ is $0$ if $n$ odd, odd if $n$ even but not divisible by 4, and even if $n$ divisible by 4.

Comment: I suspect they intended $a_n = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \ 4|n \\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$

Answer (score 3):

Another formula using the powers of $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is
$$a_n=\frac{1+i^n+(-1)^n+(-i)^n}{4}.$$
This has to do with the sum of $4$th roots of unity being zero, and the fact that when $n$ is a multiple of $4$ the terms on top are all $1.$